# Solution of non-linear Fredholm(Hammerstein) equation with non-degenerate kernel and reciprocal non-linearity

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, operator-theory, integral-equations

I have asked this question but got no response. I rephrase it so that anyone who knows operator theory and integral equations would help me out.....I faced a problem in physics which is a non-linear Fredholm integral equation(Hammerstein). It is of the form:
\begin{equation}
y(p)=f(p)+\int_0 ^{\infty}\frac{e^{ik\wedge p}}{y(k)}dk
\end{equation}
There are two subtleties: (1)The kernel is non-degenerate or non-separable.(2) The non-linearity is reciprocal. 
The kernel is symmetric as the wedge product is anti-symmetric,i.e. $\overline{K(p,k)}=K(k,p)$.
I tried solving it using the collocation method but got divergence due to it's severe bound on the upper limit.
I am now starting to work with Monte-Carlo integration and it's too complicated. That's why i want if any of you would help me.

Comment: What is the physics problem you faced?

Comment: Well, it's actually Schwinger-Dyson equations for some model in field theory.